# Did not find a deadline at the given deadline manager. Expected: <[matches a given predicate]> at <datetime> Got: <no scheduled events>

Tags: axon

I have been trying to run a test(below) on a saga using the setup below but getting the error mentioned in the title. I have tried searching for examples but the internet and axon(4.5.12) documentation is kind of thin on answers.

```
@Bean
fun deadlineManager(axonConfiguration: AxonConfiguration): DeadlineManager {
    return SimpleDeadlineManager.builder()
           .scopeAwareProvider(ConfigurationScopeAwareProvider(axonConfiguration))
           .build()
}
```

In my Axon Saga, I have

```
@SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "someId")
fun on(event: SomeEvent, deadlineManager: DeadlineManager) {
     val deadlineId = deadlineManager.schedule(
                        Duration.ofMinutes(10),
                        "Deadlinename",
                        "payload"
                    )
}
```

and

```
@DeadlineHandler(deadlineName = "Deadlinename")
fun handle(payload: String) {}
```

So in my test i have:

```
class MySagaTest {

    private val sagaTestFixture = SagaTestFixture(MySaga::class.java)
    private val deadlineManagerMock = mockk<DeadlineManager>()

    init {
        sagaTestFixture.registerResource(deadlineManagerMock)
    }

    @Test
    fun `deadline test`(){
       every {
            deadlineManagerMock.schedule(
                Duration.ofMinutes(10),
                "Deadlinename",
                "payload"
            )
        } returns "someDeadlineId"

       sagaTestFixture
        .givenAPublished(SomePriorEvent("id"))
        .whenPublishingA(SomeEvent("id"))
        .expectActiveSagas(1)
        .expectNoDispatchedCommands()
        .expectScheduledDeadlineWithName(
             Duration.ofMinutes(10),
             "Deadlinename"
         )

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the predicament is that you are wiring your own mocked out `DeadlineManager`. Axon's `SagaTestFixture` contains a specific format of the `DeadlineManager` that it uses for validating the scheduled deadlines in.

So, I would recommend you remove the `registerResource` call of the mocked `DeadlineManager` entirely. It should work from there on. If not, please let me know. I can likely look a little deeper into this.